# DataGridView in .NET Compact Framework 3.5

Tags: compact-framework

I know that there is a DataGrid control in CF. However, is there a DataGridView control in .NET Compact Framework 3.5?

Comment: Martin,
Yes, CF and Compact Framework are the same.
I am asking whether CF has DataGridView, which is different from DataGrid.

Comment: I don't think it is supported in CF.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx

The DataGridView is not supported in CF, as it is not listed in the version information section at the bottom of the page.